# Selecting the top 50 % percentage names from the columns of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this. The rows and the columns have the same name.

```
name a  b  c  d  e  f  g 
 a   10 5  4  8  5  6  4
 b   5  10 6  5  4  3  3
 c   -  4  9  3  6  5  7
 d   6  9  8  6  6  8  2
 e   8  5  4  4  14 9  6
 f   3  3  -  4  5  14 7
 g   4  5  8  9  6  7  10
```

I can get the 5 number of largest values by passing df['column_name'].nlargest(n=5) but if I have to return 50 % of the largest in descending order, is there anything that is inbuilt in pandas of it I have to write a function for it, how can I get them? I am quite new to python. Please help me out.

UPDATE : So let's take column a into consideration and it has values like 10, 5,-,6,8,3 and 4. I have to sum all of them up and get the top 50% of them. so the total in this case is 36. 50% of these values would be 18. So from column a, I want to select 10 and 8 only. Similarly I want to go through all the other columns and select 50%.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sorting is flexible :)

```
df.sort_values('column_name',ascending=False).head(int(df.shape[0]*.5))
```

**Update:** frac argument is available only on .sample(), not in .head or .tail. df.sample(frac=.5) does give 50% but head and tail expects only int. df.head(frac=.5) fails with *TypeError: head() got an unexpected keyword argument 'frac'*

**Note: on int() vs round()**

```
int(3.X) == 3 # True Where 0 >= X >=9 
round(3.45) == 3 # True
round(3.5) == 4 # True
```

So when doing .head(int/round ...) do think of what behaviour fits your need.

Updated: Requirements

> So let's take column a into consideration and it has values like 10,
>   5,-,6,8,3 and 4. I have to sum all of them up and get the top 50% of
>   them. so the total, in this case, is 36. 50% of these values would be
>   18. So from column a, I want to select 10 and 8 only. Similarly, I want to go through all the other columns and select 50%. -Matt

A silly hack would be to sort, find the cumulative sum, find the middle by dividing it with the sum total and then use that to select part of your sorted column. e.g.

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv(
pd.compat.StringIO("""name a b c d e f g 
a 10 5 4 8 5 6 4
b 5 10 6 5 4 3 3
c - 4 9 3 6 5 7
d 6 9 8 6 6 8 2
e 8 5 4 4 14 9 6
f 3 3 - 4 5 14 7
g 4 5 8 9 6 7 10"""), 
sep=' ', index_col='name'
).dropna(axis=1).apply(
pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce', downcast='signed')

x = data[['a']].sort_values(by='a',ascending=False)[(data[['a']].sort_values(by='a',ascending=False).cumsum()
                                                 /data[['a']].sort_values(by='a',ascending=False).sum())<=.5].dropna()
print(x)
```

Outcome:[image]

Comment: So let's take column a into consideration and it has values like 10, 5,-,6,8,3 and 4. I have to sum all of them up and get the top 50% of them. so the total in this case is 36. 50% of these values would be 18. So from column a, I want to select 10 and 8 only. Similarly I want to go through all the other columns and select 50%. Please do let me know if this makes sense.

Comment: Now that is a different question altogether :) I have updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

You could sort the data frame and display only 90% of the data

```
df.sort_values('column_name',ascending=False).head(round(0.9*len(df)))
```

Comment: Did you df.head(frac=0.9) gives 90%? I rarely use it but it is there ;)

Comment: This is not true. After reading Pandas documentation and testing codes, I confused sample with head, .df.sample that takes in frac as an argument but not head/tail. Therefore I  +1 your answer.

Comment: So let's take column a into consideration and it has values like 10, 5,-,6,8,3 and 4. I have to sum all of them up and get the top 50% of them. so the total in this case is 36. 50% of these values would be 18. So from column a, I want to select 10 and 8 only. Similarly I want to go through all the other columns and select 50%. Please do let me know if this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

> data.csv

```
name,a,b,c,d,e,f,g
a,10,5,4,8,5,6,4
b,5,10,6,5,4,3,3
c,-,4,9,3,6,5,7
d,6,9,8,6,6,8,2
e,8,5,4,4,14,9,6
f,3,3,-,4,5,14,7
g,4,5,8,9,6,7,10
```

> test.py

```
#!/bin/python

import pandas as pd

def percentageOfList(l, p):
    return l[0:int(len(l) * p)]

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
print(percentageOfList(df.sort_values('b', ascending=False)['b'], 0.9))
```

Comment: So let's take column a into consideration and it has values like 10, 5,-,6,8,3 and 4. I have to sum all of them up and get the top 50% of them. so the total in this case is 36. 50% of these values would be 18. So from column a, I want to select 10 and 8 only. Similarly I want to go through all the other columns and select 50%. Please do let me know if this makes sense.